# ckeditor dropdown not showing in IE compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

> I using this editor bar of ckeditor , i have it inside green div and
>   there is a another div on bottom. when i click on "font or any other,
>   which opens a dropdown" . it's hidding behind the bottom div. 
>   otherwise its showing in chrome or IE without compatibility mode. i
>   changed z-index but it's not working..

[image: this is image on IE 8 on compatibility mode]

[image: it's in chrome, showing fine]

Comment: Without code it's quite hard to spot the errors. Make a jsfiddle and post some code here.

Comment: @arbitter It's part of very large project and it's not easy to keep up code here, as many things are linked up to each other

Comment: @wikiijames: Can't you make a simplified version then? Without code it's impossible for us to help you.

Comment: @arbitter ok, i try to make a simple version and upload here

Answer (score 1):

After working out on code, i figured out. to change the z-index of top green div , is making that dropdown over white bottom div. even in IE comparability mode it's working fine now.